# Problem installing MariaDB Python bindings on Raspberry Pi OS--how to get the latest Connector/C?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I am trying to use MariaDB with Python on a Raspberry Pi 4 with the 64 bit OS. After much trial and error I cannot solve the issue of a newer Connector/C version being required. The steps I took so far:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

This installed MariaDB just fine and I can use it in a terminal. In order to install Python bindings I first installed

```
sudo apt install libmariadbclient-dev
```

but then when I try to install the Python module with

```
pip3 install mariadb
```

There is an error:

```
Collecting mariadb
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/a4/2d73d007571a5df9369eed9166150c7e067eb883cbd9ec3f97c7a48be660/mariadb-1.1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.13
```

I wonder why version 3.2.4 is required in the first place. According to the documentation, it was just released 10 days ago: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-c/

There is no repository for Raspberry Pi OS. How can I install the newest Connector/C?

Answer (score 2):

The answer for me was not to get the newest Connector/C, but to install an older version of the `mariadb` module. In my case going back to 1.0.7 was sufficient. It can be installed with

```
pip3 install -Iv mariadb==1.0.7
```

However, it seems like the newest pip version automatically falls back to the latest compatible module, so try upgrading pip first:

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

And then run the simpler command (without specific version number):

```
python3 -m pip install mariadb
```

Comment: After a lot of struggling with mariadb 1.1.5, I also ended up retro-grading mariadb, I tried with 1.1.4 first, but it also failed, I finally tried 1.0.7 as you suggested and it works ! Thanks ;)

Comment: Successfully installed mariadb-1.0.11